# Django all auth facebook login with Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs

Tags: django, facebook-login, django-allauth

Hi I am trying to implement Facebook login for my website using Django Allauth.
As we can no longer disable `Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs` I am getting an error when I try to login via facebook.

The callback URL formed at the time of Facebook login is of this format -

`https://example.com/accounts/facebook/login/callback/?code=AQB7W48oY-1XxZv2xU9iahxS80ZPs4oBNLlXWTY7Y93dclyIElEPG-jWKB5ELV7Pv11ckcRYg3L67Wfcz6xqC8yhNLBaFaOQjd4F2AEp8nfScltnY3LoY79g9NjtslCSbQnSlc_hDdBm_rxQtScz-rLChNvAJaky3KYMG_USSTkm9qdyvw5lIMdcIHQjz3CTF8KdgmuFG1T8_WvVqdGDEpfhC_PD7w5tnkcChBEowHnWR656DYa1wrMR1fbP2rqxBocNn6fKPCy_GM_DZynPp8mx0F0YP55vzw2Kv8KchB2nxCaHwQ4dRvJq785w5CfCgDVc6REhbc3CNG2KqZxdxjuG&state=eukVyjHYk04X#_=_`

This URL contains the query params `code` and `state` because of which it is not an exact match and I checked it via `Redirect URI to Check` which reported it as invalid.

So on the `authentication_error.html` I get the following error.

> {'provider': 'facebook', 'code': 'unknown', 'exception':
> OAuth2Error('Error retrieving access token:
> b'{"error":{"message":"Can\'t load URL: The domain of this URL
> isn\'t included in the app\'s domains. To be able to load this
> URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains
> field in your app
> settings.","type":"OAuthException","code":191,"fbtrace_id":"AxoTkIBeoUSKsxuWvMx-Wg4"}}'',)}

My `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` has the following URL's

1. https://example.com/accounts/facebook/login/callback/
2. https://www.example.com/accounts/facebook/login/callback/

Please help me with this issue, I have looked into all the existing issue but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing a similar issue, it could be because you missed to add this line to your settings.py file.

`ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'`